# A tab bar with a "more/others" tab

Tags: gui-design, navigation, ios, tab-bar

Our iOS app has four main screens + 3-4 less important ones. My current idea for navigation is to use a tab bar with five tabs: four for the main screens and one tab called "more/others" which includes the rest of the screens (settings, log out, help, etc.), for example, in a list view.

Something similar what the Facebook app for iOS has: 
[image: Facebook app showing "More" screen]

However, I am not sure about quality of this navigational design nor have I found any other good examples in addition to Facebook.

For example, many apps use the the "more/others" tab for adding/removing/arraigning tabs on the tab menu but in our case we do not want to do that.

Is there any other apps that use the same design or any alternatives for this design?

Apologies if this topic has been already covered. There are tons of questions about tab bars so it was a bit difficult to find any similar ones.

Answer (score 3):

The more menu on a bottom navigation menu is actually a rather common navigation pattern. Yelp, Yahoo fantasy football, Band are a few apps just on my phone that use this navigation paradigm.

There are pros and cons to any navigation approach, the main con of a bottom navigation bar being that it uses more screen real estate than say your typical off canvas navigation. However, off canvas navigation has been shown to decrease engagement in your application. Just google "Hamburger Menu" and you can read up on a lively debate about off canvas navigation. Lately, the "big" players such as Facebook, Twitter, etc. have moved back to a fixed bottom navigation menu.

As for the "more" overflow icon, I think it depends what you plan to put in there. Are the nav items in that list related in any way? For example, Spotify uses a bottom navigation menu with five items, but then also has a settings icon in the top right of the "Your Music" screen. So think about whether the nav items you plan to put in the more menu could make sense to be interspersed throughout the experience.

Personally, I love the bottom nav with a more menu because it gives you the best of both worlds of a hamurger menu and a fixed bottom nav. Plus the more icon's affordance is much clearer when it is visually grouped with other nav items.

Comment: It's actually a standard in iOS's built in apps, You get a list of icons for other sections, which can also be dragged and dropped onto the tab bar. Take a look at the iTunes Store app. It used to be used more frequently, in the Music and Videos app, but now I think only the iTunes Store app uses it.

Comment: It was just difficult to try to find apps whit the similar design if you don´t know where to look, my phone had only the Facebook. :)

We had a mobile web version of our service before and desired to move away from the hamburger menu paradigm because users switch the screens quite often. It is more convenient to have the most used screen available as tabs all the time, even with the lost screen estate.